# How to link slider bullets to relevant slide in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to simply link my slider bullets to my slider slides. Bullet 1 = slide 1, bullet 2 = slide 2 etc. I am just not to sure how to get it to match up, i know it should be fairly simple but my brain isn't working! I have setup a basic reset so that every time a bullet is clicked it removes both the active class on the bullet and the slider slide but now i need it to then add the same 2 classes to the clicked bullet and its associated slide.

Appreciate any guidance with this.

```js
var slideBullet = document.querySelectorAll('.slider__bullet');
for (var i = 0; i < slideBullet.length; i++) {
  slideBullet[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    var sliderSlide = document.querySelectorAll('.slider__slide');

    function resetSlides() {
      for (var i = 0; i < sliderSlide.length; i++) {
        sliderSlide[i].classList.remove('active');
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < slideBullet.length; i++) {
        slideBullet[i].classList.remove('active');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
  .slider {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider__slides {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider__slides.active {
  display: block;
}

.slider__bullets {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider__bullet {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #a3a3a3;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.slider__bullet.active {
  background-color: grey;
  transform: scale(1.8);
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__slides active">1</div>
  <div class="slider__slides">2</div>
  <div class="slider__slides">3</div>
  <div class="slider__slides">4</div>
  <div class="slider__slides">5</div>
  <div class="slider__bullets">
    <div class="slider__bullet active"></div>
    <div class="slider__bullet"></div>
    <div class="slider__bullet"></div>
    <div class="slider__bullet"></div>
    <div class="slider__bullet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change your jquery code,
Try below code, hope it will work for you

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slider__slides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("slider__bullet");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
 .slider {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider__slides {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider__slides.active {
  display: block;
}

.slider__bullets {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider__bullet {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #a3a3a3;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.slider__bullet.active {
  background-color: grey;
  transform: scale(1.8);
  }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__slides active">1</div>
  <div class="slider__slides">2</div>
  <div class="slider__slides">3</div>
  <div class="slider__slides">4</div>
  <div class="slider__slides">5</div>
  
  
  <div class="slider__bullets">
    <div class="slider__bullet active" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></div>
    <div class="slider__bullet" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></div>
    <div class="slider__bullet" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></div>
    <div class="slider__bullet" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></div>
    <div class="slider__bullet" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```